# Browser Summary not showing up in the Analog report

Tags: logging, analytics

I am running my IIS server log (from Windows 2000) against Analog.  For whatever reason, the resulting Results.html does not include the Browser Summary.

What am I missing?  I checked the errors.txt file and there isn't anything there that would point to the browser report missing.

Comment: I haven't seen an IIS log in so long.  Have you checked opened the file and check to see if the Is the user-agent actually in there?

Comment: Yes, it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `BROWSERREP ON`  and/or `BROWSERSUM ON` in your config? (Or are you running from the command line with `+B` and/or `+b`?) You may want to edit your question and include your Analog config and/or your command-line invocation of it.

FWIW, [Analog's documentation](http://www.analog.cx/docs/logfile.html#formats) suggests that it won't parse IIS files that contain referer and browser info:

> There are also various third-party extensions to the Microsoft format to include, for 
>   example, the browser and referrer. But they all do it in different ways, so analog can't 
>   automatically diagnose them, and again, you need to write a LOGFORMAT command for them.

That said, explicitly setting `LOGFORMAT` to one of:

- `MICROSOFT-NA` (North American date format),
- `MICROSOFT-INT` (international date format),
- `MS-EXTENDED` (Microsoft's attempt at extended format),
- `MS-COMMON` (a buggy version of common format in some versions of Microsoft software)

may get you what you want. (All descriptions copied from Analog's documentation.)

Comment: Right on the money.  I guess the default analog.cfg does not come with BROWSERREP ON and/or BROWSERSUM ON added